# prove by induction that $2^n >6n$ for $n\ge5$

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, induction

I have written the base case and induction step however i cannot seem to write the ending correctly.
Here are my steps:
base case:$n=5$ hence $2^5=32$ $32>30$ therefore the base case holds.
induction step:let $k,k\ge5$ be fixed and assume $2^k>6k$
To be shown:$2^{k+1}>6(k+1)$

Comment: You should assume $2^k>6k$ and then try to show that $2^{k+1}>6(k+1)$

Comment: That's the part i am stuck on! would this be correct? 2^k+1 > 6(k+1) = 2^k+2^k>6k+1 and then using the induction step we are left with 2^k>6k

Comment: A very rough explanation of how proof by induction works is as follows: 1) Show the statement is true for some base case (you have shown this for $n=5$), 2) Show that if we assume that the statement is true for some value of $n$, say $n=k$, then it also follows that it is true for $n=k+1$

Comment: I need to basically prove 2^k+1>6(k+1) this is the same as saying 2^k+2^k=6k+6 then i am not sure what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the answers given by others:

You are asked to prove $2^n>6n$ for $n\ge5$.

You first show that the base case is indeed true, so:
$2^5 = 32$ and $6\times 5=30$ therefore $2^5>6\times 5$

You now assume its true for some value of $n$, say $n=k$, so: $2^k>6k$

Finally you just need to prove that this implies that $2^{k+1}>6(k+1)$, so lets try the following:

We have assumed $2^k>6k$, therefore, if we multiply both sides of this by $2$ we get: $2\times2^k>2\times6k$

$\therefore 2^{k+1}>6k+6k$

$\therefore 2^{k+1}>6(k+k)$

and, since we know $k\ge5$ then we can also say that $6(k+k)>6(k+1)$

$\therefore 2^{k+1}>6(k+1)$

Comment: thank you so much that makes sense. I'm finding it a little tricky since i only just started jy maths degree!

Comment: np - I'm glad I was able to help you understand the steps to take

Comment: I try and help as many people as I can and also try to learn as much as I can from others on this site. I am not sure what you mean by "directly ask"?

Comment: thanks no worries

Answer (score 2):

Supposing $2^k > 6k$, you can multiply by $2$ and obtain $2^{k+1}> 12k$, but then $12k = 6k + 6k$ and since $k\geq 1$, you have $6k \geq 6$. Hence $12k \geq 6k + 6 = 6(k+1)$

Comment: I sort of understand what you are saying. So would I write it like this: 2^k+1=2^k+2^k and we know 2^k>6k from the induction step so then i write 2^k >1

Comment: To finish this line of proof you would need to obtain $2^k \geq 6$ so that $2^k + 2^k > 6k + 6 = 6(k+1)$. That is licit as soon as $k\geq 3$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused about what you have to do.

Let $\ P(n)\ $ be the statement: $\ 2^n > 6n.$

Then $\ P(n+1)\ $ is the statement: $\ 2^{n+1} > 6(n+1).$

The question asks you to prove that:

$P(n)$ is true

$\implies$

$P(n+1)$ is true.

Or in other words, you have to prove that, if (i.e. assuming) $P(n)$ is true, then $P(n+1)$ is true.

You are not allowed to assume that the statement $P(n+1)$ is true in your proof, for that would be using the result, which is essentially cheating.

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Description) for alternative/further explanations on how proof by induction works.

Comment: I always get stuck at that point; when I have to prove p(n+1) is true!

Comment: In your question, you write: "Assume $2^k>6(k+1)$", but I don't understand why you assume this? You should assume $2^k>6k$. And then try to show that $2^{k+1}>6(k+1)$ (if $k>5$).

Comment: 2^+1>6(+1) (if >5)  would this be correct? = 2^k+2^k>6k+6 what would go next?

Comment: Stop writing $2^k + 1$. Write $2^{k+1}$ by putting curly braces around the $k+1$. Also, $2^{k+1} = 2^k 2^1 = 2\cdot 2^k,\quad 2^{k+1} \neq 2^k\cdot 2^k.\quad 2^k\cdot 2^k = 2^{k+k} = 2^{2k}.\ $  So you're making lots of mistakes with indices, unfortunately. Try to understand where you're going wrong. And please use MathJax. You can learn how to here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference